# Connecting a radio device with controller (+ power supply)

Tags: connector, uart, ethernet, rs485, rs422

*I have a min knowledge in electronics, so I am sorry if my questions are stupid for you.*

I am studying how I can connect a radio device with a controller. The radio device is a transmitter/receiver or transceiver, for example, with Nano-D-Sub connectors.

I need an interface for a connection between the radio device and the controller. I have googled and found the following possibility for controller: RS422, RS485, ethernet.

1. If I understand correctly, I need a connector for these interfaces, right?
2. There interfaces are for data transmission, right? Can we have 4 interfaces above in one device?
3. RS422 or RS485: which one is preferable for satellite communication?
4. What should I google to find information about connecting a radio device to a controller in a satellite?

**Edit 1**

A radio device and controller are part of a satellite ( S - ,  K- and or UHF). IEE802.11b Data rate

**EDIT 2**
The following deviced were given me as examples of a radio devices which are  connected with a controller

Example of a radio device:

1. https://satsearch.co/products/endurosat-s-band-transmitter
2. https://satsearch.co/products/endurosat-x-band-transmitter

Comment: Terms like "radio device" and "controller" are much too vague, but this isn't how you go about designing a system like this. You'd start with things like: what data is being sent and at what amounts? What environment will this be in and at what distances? That is, write down a specification before anything else.

Comment: @Lundin i added some details which suppose to be studied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The connector says very little about what kind of signal is transported across. The device datasheet tells everything. So, you need to figure out what the model name of the radio device is, and read its datasheet.

You generally don't start choosing complex satellite hardware for the low-level interface it works with. You need a satellite modem, look which satellite modems have the functionality you need, and *afterwards* look which interfaces candidates have.

> If I understand correctly, I need a connector for these interfaces, right?

Hm, not necessarily. Radio interfaces might just as well be integrated onto the same PCB. It's not clear what kind of system you're referring to – it seems to have something to do with satellites though. Honestly, a satellite is probably not the first thing you should build. Too hard. Too many restrictions. Too costly. No chance to ever service the device.

> There interfaces are for data transmission, right?

Not interfaces, but wire-bound communication standards. Yes, they're for transmitting data.

> Can we have 4 interfaces above in one device?

Yes. Also, RS422 and RS485 are basically the same, with the latter doing duplex. But: comparing space wire and ethernet to "UART" is comparing things from a very different level of specification. Saying "UART" doesn't even specify voltages, nor word lengths, nor speeds, nor handshake methods or really anything, whereas saying "Ethernet" defines a whole electrical interface, cabling, speeds, packet format, adressing, methods of access arbitration...

> What should I google to find information about connecting a radio device to a controller in a satellite?

Nothing, at this point. You're trying to build an electronic device, a satellite. That's very complex, and it requires actual understanding! The interfaces you mention are *not* really plug and play, as in plugging a USB thumb drive into your Laptop working out of the box; there's things you'll need to do to make the devices actually talk to each other. You need to start with a bit of basics, no way around that.

Comment: `"The device datasheet tells everything. ..." ` In a datasheet I can find inforamtion about data rate, frequency, modulation, power consumtion, voltage , rf connector... It is given the radio device has D-sub connector, but via this connector I can connect all interfaces ( RS422, RS485, ethernet, UART ,space wire). Which one of the paramters in the datasheet are important for me?

Comment: I don't know your device, nor your datasheet. I can't tell you. The datasheet will definitely tell you how to connect to the device, else it's not much use.

Comment: can  RS 422 be connected with RS 485? if a device A has RS 422 and a device B has RS 485?

Comment: this question makes no sense. You can connect anything to anything, whether it does something useful is a different question. Link to your datasheet **by editing your question**. Why leave us guessing? Really, you're assuming this is like plugging USB devices into a PC, but in reality "RS422" or "RS485" only tells us how "high" and "low" are defined, electrically. It doesn't even define what is a 1 or a 0, and how many 1s or 0s are "1ms high". You really need to dig deeper here. *You are not at a point where you're able to choose satellite components*.

Comment: I added 3 radio devices which I can use in my work.

Comment: the radio device and the controller are two devices which are connected. For the connection we use a connecter with an interface:  RS422, RS485, ethernet, UART or space wire. Do i understand correctly?

Comment: Then I don't understand your question. Datasheet of e.g. the first very clearly states "data interface IEEE 802.3 1000BASE-T", so that's that. That answer the question of what you can use. How that Gigabit Ethernet is mapped to the connector is part of documentation to be inquired from the vendor or that comes with the device, and I'd see it as tiny detail.

Comment: "How that Gigabit Ethernet is mapped to the connector is part of documentation to be inquired..." , it is my rask to find it. the first link gives "data interface IEEE 802.3 1000BASE-T", I need to "re-design" and make a device ieee802.11 (b, g,n) with interfaces in OP...

Comment: 802.11 is wireless. You cannot "redesign" a wired device to do wireless. All you can do is attach a 802.11 access point to the gigabit interface, and that makes little sense, data rate wise. Plus, doing WLAN on a satellite makes no sense at all, and you'd probably be in violation of *multiple* launch requirements for a satellite payload and legal operation requirements for a satellite transponder.

Comment: completely unrelated question: please do not ask in comments.